# Python/Kivy : `up` and `down` Keyboard interface on Tree View in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I want to use `up` and `down` Keyboard interface on `Tree View`.When i click on `name` then `Tree View` popup shows And `up`,`down` key working good.But i type something into `TextInput` for filter `row` after use `up` and `down` key for select row then it gives error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent_node'` .How to  `row` select using `up` and `down` keys?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty
Window.size = (500, 400)


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeViewGroup(Popup):
    tree_view = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    filter_text = StringProperty('')
    tree = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeViewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_tree_view_root()
        rows = ['test{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 20)]
        self.tree = [{'node_id': r, 'children': []} for r in rows]
        self.tv.bind(minimum_height=self.tree_view.setter('height'))
        self.create_tree_view_branch(self.tree)

    def create_tree_view_root(self):
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)

    def create_tree_view_branch(self, obj):
        for branch in obj:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.tree_view.add_widget(self.tv)

    def on_open(self, *args):
        self.filter_text = App.get_running_app().root.name.text
        self._request_keyboard()
        self.ti.focus = True

    def dismiss_callback(self):
        if self._keyboard is not None:
            self._keyboard.release()
        self.tree_view.clear_widgets()
        self.dismiss()
        App.get_running_app().root.name.focus = True

    def _request_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        if self.tv.selected_node is None:
            self.tv.select_node(self.tv.root.nodes[0])

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.release()
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        node = self.tv.selected_node
        _, key = keycode
        if key in ('down', 'up'):
            parent = node.parent_node
            ix = parent.nodes.index(node)
            nx = ix+1 if key == 'down' else ix-1
            next_node = parent.nodes[nx % len(parent.nodes)]
            self.tv.select_node(next_node)
            self.scroll.scroll_to(next_node)
        elif key in ('enter', 'numpadenter'):
            App.get_running_app().root.name.text = node.text
            print(node.text)
            self.dismiss_callback()

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def filter(self, value):
        self.tree_view.clear_widgets()
        self.create_tree_view_root()
        filtered_tree = []
        for node in self.tree:
            if value.lower() in node['node_id'].lower():
                filtered_tree.append(node)
        self.create_tree_view_branch(filtered_tree)
        self._request_keyboard()
        self.ti.focus = True


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeViewGroup()
            self.popup.open()


class Group(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TreeViewLabel>:
    color_selected: [1, 0, 0, 1]  if self.is_selected else [.1, .1, .1, 1]  # red
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.name.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss_callback()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    tree_view: tree_view
    title: "Select"
    title_size: 17
    size: 800, 800
    auto_dismiss: False
    scroll: scroll
    ti:ti

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id : ti
            text: root.filter_text
            size_hint_y: .13
            multiline: False
            on_text: root.filter(self.text)

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint: 1, .9

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                id: tree_view

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 1}
            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss_callback()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss_callback()

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    name: name

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text: root.display_groups(self)

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

Comment: What does it mean: *But i type something into TextInput for filter row then how to use up, down and enter Keyboard interface*?

Comment: What should the key do up and down after typing the TextInput ?, again I ask you to be detailed, we do not know what you expect, always assume it and read your question aloud, and ask if others understand it.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry i will remember next time. After typing the TextInput label to be selected with the up and down keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Select a row - press ENTER or Mouse click

Use up or down arrow to scroll, and press ENTER to select a specific row. *Note: Alternatives, mouse click to select a specific row.*

## Pass input string from Name to Filter

To pass the whole word e.g. *test*, replace *on_focus* with *on_text_validate*.

## DRY - Don't Repeat Yourselves

There are duplicate codes, I have turned them into modules for easy maintenance.

```
def create_treeview_root(self):
...
def create_treeview_branch(self, obj):
...
def dismiss_callback(self):
```

## Snippet

```
GroupScreen:
    ...
        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.display_groups(self)
```

## Popup Events on_open

Removed the binding in *__init__* because the *on_open* is automatically binded and it is fired when the Popup is opened.
[Popup Events » API](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html)

```
class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    ...

    def __init__(self,obj, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
        self.bind(on_open=self.on_open)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty
Window.size = (500, 400)


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


class CustomTextInput(TextInput):

    def do_cursor_movement(self, action, control=False, alt=False):
        if not self._lines:
            return
        if action in ('cursor_up', 'cursor_down'):
            App.get_running_app().root.popup._request_keyboard()
        return super(CustomTextInput, self).do_cursor_movement(action, control=control, alt=alt)


class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeViewGroup(Popup):
    tree_view = ObjectProperty(None)
    filter_text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    filter_text = StringProperty('')
    tree = ListProperty([])
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)

    keycodes = {
        # specials keys
        'backspace': 8, 'tab': 9, 'enter': 13, 'rshift': 303, 'shift': 304,
        'alt': 308, 'rctrl': 306, 'lctrl': 305,
        'super': 309, 'alt-gr': 307, 'compose': 311, 'pipe': 310,
        'capslock': 301, 'escape': 27, 'spacebar': 32, 'pageup': 280,
        'pagedown': 281, 'end': 279, 'home': 278, 'left': 276, 'up':
        273, 'right': 275, 'down': 274, 'insert': 277, 'delete': 127,
        'numlock': 300, 'print': 144, 'screenlock': 145, 'pause': 19,

        # F1-15
        'f1': 282, 'f2': 283, 'f3': 284, 'f4': 285, 'f5': 286, 'f6': 287,
        'f7': 288, 'f8': 289, 'f9': 290, 'f10': 291, 'f11': 292, 'f12': 293,
        'f13': 294, 'f14': 295, 'f15': 296,
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeViewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = None

        self.create_tree_view_root()
        rows = ['test{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 20)]
        self.tree = [{'node_id': r, 'children': []} for r in rows]
        self.tv.bind(minimum_height=self.tree_view.setter('height'))
        self.create_tree_view_branch(self.tree)

    def create_tree_view_root(self):
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)

    def create_tree_view_branch(self, obj):
        for branch in obj:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.tree_view.add_widget(self.tv)

    def on_open(self, *args):
        self.obj = self.filter_text_input
        self.filter_text_input.focus = True
        self.filter_text = App.get_running_app().root.name.text

    def dismiss_callback(self):
        if self._keyboard is not None:
            self._keyboard.release()
        self.tree_view.clear_widgets()
        self.dismiss()
        App.get_running_app().root.name.focus = True

    def _request_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        if (self.tv.selected_node is None) \
                and (len(self.tv.root.nodes) > 0):
            self.tv.select_node(self.tv.root.nodes[0])
        else:
            self.filter_text_input.focus = True

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.release()
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        node = self.tv.selected_node
        _, key = keycode
        if key in ('down', 'up'):
            parent = node.parent_node
            ix = parent.nodes.index(node)
            nx = ix+1 if key == 'down' else ix-1
            next_node = parent.nodes[nx % len(parent.nodes)]
            self.tv.select_node(next_node)
            self.scroll.scroll_to(next_node)
        elif key in ('enter', 'numpadenter'):
            App.get_running_app().root.name.text = node.text
            print(node.text)
            self.dismiss_callback()

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        if self.string_to_keycode(key) == -1:
            self.filter_text += key
            self.obj.focus = True

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def string_to_keycode(self, value):
        '''Convert a string to a keycode number according to the
        :attr:`TreeViewGroup.keycodes`. If the value is not found in the
        keycodes, it will return -1.
        '''
        return TreeViewGroup.keycodes.get(value, -1)

    def filter(self, value):
        self.tree_view.clear_widgets()
        self.create_tree_view_root()
        filtered_tree = []
        for node in self.tree:
            if value.lower() in node['node_id'].lower():
                filtered_tree.append(node)
        self.create_tree_view_branch(filtered_tree)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeViewGroup()
            self.popup.open()


class Group(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomTextInput>:
    size_hint_y: .13
    multiline: False

<TreeViewLabel>:
    color_selected: [1, 0, 0, 1]  if self.is_selected else [.1, .1, .1, 1]  # red
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.name.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss_callback()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    tree_view: tree_view
    filter_text_input: filter_text_input
    title: "Select"
    title_size: 17
    size: 800, 800
    auto_dismiss: False
    scroll: scroll

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"

        CustomTextInput:
            id: filter_text_input
            text: root.filter_text
            on_text:
                root.filter_text = self.text
                root.filter(self.text)

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint: 1, .9

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                id: tree_view

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 1}
            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss_callback()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss_callback()

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    name: name

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text: root.display_groups(self)

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Filter Popup]
[image: Img03 - Scroll to bottom]
[image: Img04 - Enter pressed]
[image: Img05 - filter text]
[image: Img06 - clicked OK button]

Comment: Please refer to my updated post and it addressed passing input string from Name to Filter, and also the scrolling.

Comment: thanks again for help. I updated post.I changed event `on_text_validate` to `on_text`.I set `focus=True` on `filter`. When `Tree View` open then `filter` TextInput focused but `up` and `down` key not works.Can i focused `filter` TextInput continue untill `Tree View` open and select row using  `up` and `down` key. `Focus` property and `up` and `down` key not working `simultaneously`.

Comment: I have updated my post as per your changes by inserting **self.filter_text_input.focus = True** before *self._request_keyboard()* in method *on_open*. Scrolling up and down is working now.

Comment: thanks for reply.It's not working when open `Tree View` then doesn't focus `filter` TextInput and i can't type continuously into `filter` TextInput beacuase it unfocused after every `letter`.I have to click into `filter` TextInput again and again for type

Comment: When the filter text has focus, the keyboard for the treeview will defocus. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `keyboard` is being closed, so keyboard events are ignored, when you click on a `TextInput`. You can arrange for the `keyboard` to be requested again when you hit `Enter` in the `Select` `TextInput` by restricting it to single line and adding a `on_text_validate:` item, like this in your kv file:

```
    TextInput:
        id : ti
        size_hint_y: .13
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.validate()
        on_text: root.filter(self.text)
```

And the in your `TreeViewGroup` class, add the validate method as:

```
def validate(self):
    self.on_open()
```

This will call your `on_open` method and set up your keyboard events again.

Comment: You have to hit `enter` in the `TextInput` for it to work.